# dlink drivers from d-link dwa-182 kubuntu 22.04

Tags: wireless, d-link

I have run the install.sh script for the d-link dwa-182. The script successfully installs and says module activated.  What do I do after rebooting to enable WiFi.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the result of the terminal commands: `lsusb` and also: `lsmod | grep 88`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)